# Automaticly embed recent YouTube video with Channel ID

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

**This working**:

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=VanossGaming" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But for **CHANNEL ID** don't work.

**This one don't work:**

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=UCKqH_9mk1waLgBiL2vT5b9g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So how to use this Iframe for **CHANNEL ID**.

Thanks for all answers..

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to achieve? Why don't you just use the first URL?

Comment: Beacouse my channel dont have username, I don't know how to use for CHANNEL ID.

Comment: That was just example. 
You can convert username to CHANNEL ID, but not channel id to username.
This is my real URL: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHJJyhVZk9ZnYHm0PweZY9g/